# How come only part of the interior of this path is used for clipping?

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

Here is an example document and the output I get from it.

```
\documentclass[convert={size=480}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ little circle/.style = { fill = black,
                                   shape = circle,
                                   minimum size = 1.5mm,
                                   inner sep = 0mm,
                                   outer sep = 0mm},
          concentric circles/.style = {draw = gray!90, very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\concentriccircles{\foreach \r in {1.5, ..., 19} {circle (\r mm)};}
    \foreach \name/\x/\y in {A/8/30, B/16/-24, C/-30/8} {
        \node [little circle] (\name) at (\x mm, \y mm) {};
    }
    \node [little circle] (P) at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {};
    \foreach \name/\origin/\destination in {H/A/B, J/B/C, K/C/A} {
        \path (\origin) -- (\destination) coordinate [midway] (\name);
        \path (P) -- (\name) node [pos = 1.6, little circle] (\name 2) {};
    }
    \draw [concentric circles] (P) \concentriccircles;
    \foreach \x/\y/\v/\c in {A/B/H/green, B/C/J/red, C/A/K/blue} {
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (\x) .. controls (P) .. (\y) -- (\v 2) -- (\x); % (*)
            \draw [concentric circles, draw = \c] (P) \concentriccircles;
        \end{scope}
    }
    \begin{scope}[very thick]
        \foreach \x/\y/\c in {A/B/red, B/C/blue, C/A/green} {
            \draw [\c] (\x) .. controls (P) .. (\y);
        }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[very thick, red]
        \path [use as bounding box];
        \clip (A) circle [radius = 25mm];
        \draw (A) .. controls (P) .. (B);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't understand why the clipping area excludes the triangle `(A, B, H2)` (`(B, C, J2)` and `(C, A, K2)`). You can see it does because the concentric circles beyond the line between A and B (B and C, C and A) are still grey.

## Edit

Here is what it looks like if you add the `draw` option to the `\clip` command at `(*)`.

[image]

Comment: You can see the clipping area using an option `\clip[draw]`

Comment: See what happens if you do `\clip[draw] (\x) .. controls (P) .. (\y) -- (\v) ;` that is, non closed path. Strange!

Comment: @Sigur, if you do that then the clip area appears the same, though if you look closely you can see that it stops a short distance from the drawn line (which is drawn to halfway between A and B, as you would expect).

Comment: Try with coordinates instead of nodes... Or use `\x.center`, `\y.center`, `\v 2.center`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you build a path with nodes, TikZ cuts this path into several segments to avoid the content of nodes.

To build your closed clipping path, use coordinates instead of nodes... or use `\x.center`, `\y.center`, `\v 2.center`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert={size=480}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ little circle/.style = { fill = black,
                                   shape = circle,
                                   minimum size = 1.5mm,
                                   inner sep = 0mm,
                                   outer sep = 0mm},
          concentric circles/.style = {draw = gray!90, very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\concentriccircles{\foreach \r in {1.5, ..., 19} {circle (\r mm)};}
    \foreach \name/\x/\y in {A/8/30, B/16/-24, C/-30/8} {
        \node [little circle] (\name) at (\x mm, \y mm) {};
    }
    \node [little circle] (P) at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {};
    \foreach \name/\origin/\destination in {H/A/B, J/B/C, K/C/A} {
        \path (\origin) -- (\destination) coordinate [midway] (\name);
        \path (P) -- (\name) node [pos = 1.6, little circle] (\name 2) {};
    }
    \draw [concentric circles] (P) \concentriccircles;
    \foreach \x/\y/\v/\c in {A/B/H/green, B/C/J/red, C/A/K/blue} {
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (\x.center) .. controls (P.center) .. (\y.center)
            -- (\v 2.center) -- cycle; % (*)
            \draw [concentric circles, draw = \c] (P) \concentriccircles;
        \end{scope}
    }
    \begin{scope}[very thick]
        \foreach \x/\y/\c in {A/B/red, B/C/blue, C/A/green} {
            \draw [\c] (\x) .. controls (P) .. (\y);
        }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[very thick, red]
        \path [use as bounding box];
        \clip (A) circle [radius = 25mm];
        \draw (A) .. controls (P) .. (B);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it makes a difference whether it's a coordinate or a node? If `x` is a node, then isn't saying `(x)` the same as saying `(x.center)`? The TikZ/PGF manual doesn't say anything about not being able to clip using paths that make use of nodes-as-coordinates, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Hammerite If you build a path with nodes, TikZ cuts this path into several segments to avoid the content of nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I feel like this could be addressed in the TikZ manual.